# angular-ui IE8 accordion

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Using the Angular-UI bootstrap accordion in IE8 the tabs do not expand. Here is the error I am receiving using IE 8's F12

```
 Error: Unexpected call to method or property access.undefined 
 Error: No controller: accordion<div class="accordion-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="c in categories" heading="{{c.Name}}"> 
 Error: No controller: accordion<div class="accordion-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="c in categories" heading="{{c.Name}}"> 
 Error: No controller: accordion<div class="accordion-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="c in categories" heading="{{c.Name}}"> 
 Error: No controller: accordion<div class="accordion-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="c in categories" heading="{{c.Name}}"> 
 Error: No controller: accordion<div class="accordion-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="c in categories" heading="{{c.Name}}"> 
 Error: No controller: accordion<div class="accordion-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="c in categories" heading="{{c.Name}}"> 
 Error: No controller: accordion<div class="accordion-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="c in categories" heading="{{c.Name}}"> 
 Error: No controller: accordion<div class="accordion-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="c in categories" heading="{{c.Name}}">
```

Has anyone had a similar issue and been able to resolve it?

Comment: Can we see your code or can you reproduce the issue on jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: Sure, here is what i've extracted out....still having the same issue, but fewer expected accordion tabs

http://loganweilenman.com/accordion-test/test-accordion.html

Comment: See solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15590746/angularjs-error-unexpected-call-to-method-or-property-access-undefined-only

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the main issue was IE not liking `<accordion>` used `<div accordion></div>` instead

Answer (score 4):

IE8 won't recognize custom elements. If you need to use the `accordion` directive as an element instead of an attribute, you'll have to define the element so IE won't complain. This simple script will do the trick.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.createElement('accordion');
    document.createElement('accordion-group');
    document.createElement('accordion-heading');
</script>
```

Otherwise, just use the directive in its attribute form.

Answer (score 1):

Another gotchya that I just encountered is that you can't put the ng-controller on the same element as `<div accordion>` in ie8. Took me a lot of trail-and-error to figure that out.

I had to replace

```
<div accordion ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    ...
</div>
```

with

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div accordion>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```