# AngularJS: "Error: Unexpected call to method or property access.undefined" only in IE 8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Have you ever had the error "Error: Unexpected call to method or property access.undefined" only IE8? What was causing it? How did you solve it?

-- Note: It assumes the same code works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari

**Edit: Context**

I'm building a facebook page tab plugin with AngularJS + Google App Engine Python.

I use a **dozen custom directives** either written by me or by the angular-ui team and 4-5 controllers.

Everything works fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but not in IE8.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532864/angular-ui-ie8-accordion

Comment: It looks like you've already answered your own question, but in future, it would really help people to give answers if you specified a bit more about what your page contains. Where in your code does the error occur? What JS libraries are you using? Do you have an example you can show us? etc.

Comment: @Spudley Just added additional context to better frame the question

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem is that IE8 does not recognize "custom" elements.

Use "replace:true" in your directives declaration that are in element form (restrict: 'E') and use IE shiv (I used angular-ui's IE shiv and declared my custom tags there).

See more on the links below:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1933
http://angular-ui.github.com/#ieshiv

Comment: if this answer solved the problem, you should mark it as 'accepted' using the tick icon (even if it was you answering your own question).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery the problem can be solved by modifying the jQuery file.
Add your custom elements to the list of "nodeNames":

```
var nodeNames = "abbr|article|aside|audio|bdi|canvas|data|datalist|details|figcaption|figure|footer|" +
    "header|hgroup|mark|meter|nav|output|progress|section|summary|time|video|accordion|accordion-group|accordion-heading",
```

More information ca be found on http://blog-it.hypoport.de/2013/08/24/how-to-make-your-angularjs-app-work-in-ie-8/