# Why does this jQuery code cause IE8 error: "UNEXPECTED CALL TO METHOD OR PROPERTY ACCESS"

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

EDIT: I'm using jQuery 1.8.3.

In the code below something fails and cause a javascript error in IE8, with the message "UNEXPECTED CALL TO METHOD OR PROPERTY ACCESS". Since it's in IE8, it's very hard to pinpoint exactly where the problem occurs.

Can you guys help me figure out what could be the problem here? Is there a jQuery function run here that cause this type of error?

```
clsLanguage.prototype.refreshTranslation = function () {

"use strict";

if (!this.disableliveupdate) {
    $('body').unbind('contentchange');
}

// if translation file was found look for elements to translate
    var tmp_cls = this;
    $('[data-language]').each(function () {
        // html element to do the translation on
        var html_element = $(this);
        // look for the elements language in the current language file
        if (tmp_cls.language_strings[html_element.attr('data-language')]) {

            $.each(tmp_cls.language_strings[html_element.attr('data-language')], function (key, value) { 
                if (key === 'innerHTML') {
                    html_element.html(value);
                } else if (key !== 'description') { //we skip description key, is just used as comment of the value
                    html_element.attr(key,value);
                }
            });

        } else {
            html_element.html(html_element.attr('data-language'));
        }

    });
    if (!this.disableliveupdate) {
        $('body').bind('contentchange', function () {
            //console.log('contentchange triggered');
            tmp_cls.refreshTranslation();
        });
    }

};
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: remember to use old jquery 1.x branch for old IE's!

Comment: Have you tried outcommenting/deleting the `"use strict"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to answer without anything more specific than the error message so please try to whittle it down a bit more. With the info given:

1. It could be one of the calls to `.html()`:

   ```
   ...
   html_element.html(value);
   ...
   html_element.html(html_element.attr('data-language'));
   ```

   `.html()` [internally](https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) uses `.innerHtml`. Your error could occur because `html_element` is an element on which that can't be called (see the [corresponding MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897.aspx)), for example:

   - elements without closing tag (`input`)
   - elements where `innerHtml` is read-only (`tr`)
2. If the page in question includes [HTML5-only](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6286) or [custom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15590782/3385618) elements that could also be the cause.

Comment: Holy crap, this solved it. The problem was using .html() on a couple of input fields.