# Select2 in IE8 throws 'parentNode.disabled' is null or not an object

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I'm using Select2 3.4.6 with Angular-UI select2 directive and jQuery 1.8.3

Only on IE8, the select2 is not working properly:
Every click on the select2 input or the drop down result with this error:
**Error: 'parentNode.disabled' is null or not an object**

(In any other browser, the select2 is working just fine..)

Comment: add a js fiddle demo if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [angular-ui IE8 accordion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532864/angular-ui-ie8-accordion)